# Uncaught error using async function with ngrok

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I have the code:
`async function getUrl() { let url = await ngrok.connect(3000) return url } let url = await getUrl()`. I get an uncaught error on the last line. What am I doing wrong? the url variable in both are showing string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call it with the await keyword.

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
async function getUrl() { let url = await ngrok.connect(3000) return url } 
let url = getUrl()
```

Comment: Now it doesn't raise any errors, so thank you, but the value of url in line 2 is still a promise for some reason. Both instances of url in the function are strings.

Comment: @WasteofSpaceYT I don't fully understand how you want it to work, becuase you didn't explain in the question how you want it to work you only asked about the error. I think you should ask another question and explain the outcome that you're looking for.